# iAd testing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, iad

I'm having a bit of a problem testing iAd on the iPhone and on the simulator. The methods that are called when the ad is loaded or failed don't seem to be called when testing and Apple doesn't want apps to show empty frames when there are no ads to display.

Basically, what I did was to hide the AdView and show it only when the bannerViewDidLoadAd: is called (if the view isn't being shown already). I've placed some NSLogs on both the bannerViewDidLoadAd: and bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:, but when I run on both the simulator or on the device, nothing is ever logged.

Is this the normal behavior when simulating/testing an app with iAds? Is there any way of making sure it's actually working properly?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: My personal experience has been that calls to bannerViewDidLoadAd come reliably, but calls to didFailToReceiveAdWithError do not.  I wish I understood this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you've set the delegate on your iAd to point to the ViewController or class containing the bannerViewDidLoadAd and bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError methods?